Extract data from dataframe not matching pattern
I have a dataframe containing two columns, one with date of birth and one with date of analysis.
The DOB data is messy and sometimes contains extra characters or letters etc, so I need to clean it up. I want to get rid of all the rows where the DOB is NOT matching dddddd-dddd. But I also want to extract the "problems" into a separate list so I can have a look at them. DOB in Sweden is constructed YYMMDD-NNNN where NNNN is a 4 digit extra number which is unique to each person.
So I thought I could create a pattern and extract the data matching that pattern, but can't figure out how to also extract the data NOT matching that pattern into a separate dataframe.



DOB
Date_analysis




800202-6598
240512


790512-9984
240711


840821-R001
230407



The final idea is to be able to calculate the age of the patient at the time of analysis. So I assume I have to extract the DOB without the NNNN, and then compare to the date of analysis. The dates are lacking the century so also need to figure out how to fix that..
I tried creating a pattern and then filter out the data that matches the pattern, which works
DOB_pattern = r'(\d{6})-(\d{4})'
filtered = df[df["DOB"].str.contains(DOB_pattern)]

But how do I also get the data not matching the pattern?

df[~df["DOB"].str.contains(DOB_pattern)]?

You use the unary operator ~ (tilde) to invert your boolean series. As for the pattern, consider DOB_pattern = r'^\d{6}-\d{4}$' (starts with 6 digits, then -, then ends with 4 digits). Apart from throwing a UserWarning, your current pattern will not filter out something like 'START800202-6598'.

Thanks that works! Ans thanks for the reminder of the ^
